# What criteria must be met to earn a 3 stars rank?

Tags: mario-kart-8

How do you earn a 3 stars rank in *Mario Kart 8*?

I saw somewhere that said that you have to cross (the finish line) with 10 coins, or get first place. However, I achieved both cases playing alone and in multiplayer with friends, and no stars were given.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

3 Stars are given if you finish the Grand Prix with 60 points.

In other words, you must reach first place in every race.

Comment: Are you sure? We already have some Grand Pix with 3 stars, and one or two stars on others. And I do not remember a time where all four races were finished with first place.

Comment: @PatrickBard. I've got 3 stars on over 12 Grand Prix, and every time I had to finish each of the 4 races in first place. As soon as I place second in even just one race, I get 2 stars.

Comment: Oh, I tought they were get one at time... What you said make more sense. Maybe I just don't remember when we got 3 stars, but do you think it's different when yoy play in multiplayer. Like getting two first place one each player?

Comment: @PatrickBard. I haven't played online yet, so I don't know about that. If you're talking about local multiplayer, you probably need one player to always get first. The star rating is determined through points, and 60 points (the maximum) is needed for 3 stars.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about local multiplayer. I am playing right now, and I noticed what what you said. Thank you :D

Comment: By the way, what's the pontuation for one star? I just got 2 first places and no star.

Comment: @PatrickBard: I think it's 55 points. That's the lowest point value I have recieved a star for.

Comment: Me and my brother have played multiple grand prix in local multiplayer. 2 first places are needed for 1 star (in one grand prix, we were both awarded a 1 star result as we got 2 1sts and 2 2nd places each); 3+2nd place for 2 stars, and 4 1st places for 3 stars. If you got 2 first places and your other two finishes weren't 2nd places, that explains why you didn't get a star.

Answer (score 12):

1 Star > Earn 54 or 55 points (Two 1st and Two 2nd place finishes OR Three 1st and One 3rd or 4th Place finish)

2 Stars > Earn 57 Points (Three 1st place finishes and One 2nd place finish)

3 Stars > Earn 60 Points (Four 1st place finishes)